# how to make a graph data structure from data structures for nodes and arcs?

Tags: graph, nodes, kruskals-algorithm

i have made the following node and arc structs:

```
struct arc
{
int length;
string start;
string end;

    arc(int k,string s,string e)
    {
    this->length = k;
    this->start = s;
    this->end = e;
    }
};

struct node
{
string name;
double x;
double y;
vector<arc> link;

node(string n,double xx,double yy)
    {
    this->name = n;
    this->x = xx;
    this->y = yy;
    }
};
```

now i want to make a graph data structure such that i will be able to implement Kruskal's algorithm on it.
i cant understand how can i utilize these two structs.
each node store its name and co-ordinates plus the info about the arcs going to or from it.
so i have a cluster of nodes but how do i link everything together. there is no root node here. what should i add to my graph class?
i have searhced adjacency lists and matrix but could not understand how to relate my idea to them? kindly explain

Answer (score 0):

You need to define a criteria to compare two arcs and determinate which one is "smaller".

Given the coordinates of two nodes, know how to compare them. 
Order your arcs by your criteria. 
Start with an empty graph with all node but no arcs. 
Use the DisjointSet structure to maintain info about your connected components (to avoid cycles) 
Add your arcs to the graph from the smaller to the biggest, and ignore the arc if make a cycle. 
 
Kruskal algorithm: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Kruskal's_algorithm 
 
DisjointSet: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Disjoint-set_data_structure